# Strange operation of setState with an array inside

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a situation

```
const [myMessages, setMyMessages] = useState([])
```

At some point I call (when downloading data from Firebase)

```
setMyMessages([...myMessages, newMessage])
```

I have this state process for the application process (my logs, I display the status of `myMessages` at various times when the program is running)

```
useEffect() Objects(myMessages) [{"id":"-M3mdwTZw4EtDhQ3zOU6","content":"Y1"}]

useEffect() Objects(myMessages) [{"id":"-M3mdyF6lQE26V1hpTfu","content":"Y2"}]

useEffect() Objects(myMessages) [{"id":"-M3mdyF6lQE26V1hpTfu","content":"Y2"}]

useEffect() Objects(myMessages) [{"id":"-M3mdyF6lQE26V1hpTfu","content":"Y2"}]

useEffect() Objects(myMessages) [{"id":"-M3mdyF6lQE26V1hpTfu","content":"Y2"},{"id":"-M3me-0bcmdPLZxCKZbT","content":"Y3"}]
```

The method should retrieve the current `State` and add a new one
Ultimately, they should be `Y1, Y2, Y3`

Here you can see the strange course of writing to State and ultimately `Y1` is omitted

What could be the reason?

EDIT:

Application navigation:

```
function MainStackNavigator() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name='Main' component={Main} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

The code is in the Main component so it is in the main application component (except for the `App`)

Comment: I... don't understand the massive block of `useEffect` code you're showing. What is that supposed to be?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans This is `console.log()` which I call in `useEffect()`. I display what the `myMessages` object looks like when `useEffect()` is called

Comment: I don't see that useEffect but I am almost sure that there are multiple places that want to set messages (calling setMyMessages) and you have empty [] as second argument of useEffect so it uses initial myMessages, you should add it as a dependency, but it might not solve it anyways, but it would be problem with this 100%
TLDR: don't try to do all side effect in one useEffect

Comment: Please reread [how to ask a good question[(/help/how-to-ask) and then update your post so that it has all the relevant details and code: run though the standard [mcve] exercise and if after reducing you still didn't spot the problem on your own, that's the code that should be in your post, not what you currently have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned **useEffect**. Most time, when you have weird outcome is because you may forget to **add dependencies** in your useEffect query. Happened to the best of us. You can simply change how you setMyMessages or **add your state to the dependency array**

```
useEffect(()=>{
 // try set state like this
 setMyMessages((myPreviosState)=>
   [...myPreviosState, newMessage])
},[])
```

or

```
 useEffect(()=>{
     // try set state like this
     setMyMessages([...myMessages, newMessage])
    },[myMessages // your dependency])
```

so the state is updated correct. Why it happened? because **useEffect is work in a closure**, where they get the snapshot of the first initialization. Further update to **it will not be update in the closure**. You can read about *closure*.

I hope this help you.

Comment: The problem is solved by using `setMyMessages((myMessages) => [... myMessages, newMessage])`.  I used the way without `(myMessages)`. I have not encountered this problem before

Comment: I am glad, it solves your problem. Please mark the answer as correct, so it is closed. For the explanation of why. Because of 'closure' which useEffect is designed in. When u use useEffect. The function inside will capture the first initial states outside. After rerender, all the state updated but not inside of useEffect closure. These state will not be updated. So, dependency comes to rescue. By putting it in it. The little array. The closure will know: oh the state is updated. Also, with the tweak of setMyMessages(previosState=>return newstate)) will insert provide the latest state.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid Using setState inside useEffect because it create dependency for useEffect. So create another method for fetching the data and setting the state and call that method from useEffect. By doing this, there will be no dependency and no error;

```
const fetchAndSetState = () => {
  // perform your task here
}

useEffect(() => {
   fetchAndSetState();
},[])
```

Comment: There is a problem with this as well. useEffect is a closure. Declaring function outside of useEffect will result in the same outcome of not updating the latest value. Try read the doc for closure from Mozilla.

Comment: It is perfectly fine to setState in useEffect. U can either add it to your dependency or use the variant of useState with setMyState(latestState => your logic)